# How to build a LINQ expression with Contains method from IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, contains, expressionbuilder

I'm trying to build a LINQ expression, to filter values from a int property:

```
protected IQueryable<T> Some(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
    // "Col_id" (int property)
    var property = Expression.Property(parameter, "Col_id");

    MethodInfo method = typeof(Enumerable).
                        GetMethods().
                        Where(x => x.Name == "Contains").
                        Single(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 2).
                        MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));

    // ids = { 2, 4, 8 } etc...
    var value = Expression.Constant(ids, typeof(IEnumerable<int>));
    var containsMethod = Expression.Call(method, property, value); // exception

    var aDelegate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(containsMethod, parameter);

    table = myDataContext.GetTable<T>();

    return table.AsQueryable().Where(aDelegate);
}
```

I'm trying to get something like: `(x => ids.Contains(x.Col_id))`, but an exception is thrown:

> Expression of type 'System.Int32' cannot be used for type parameter
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[T] from 'Boolean
>   Contains[T](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[T], T)' method

Comment: just from the two errors I think you need to put MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Func<T, bool>));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me like you've just got the arguments the wrong way round.

This:

```
Expression.Call(method, property, value)
```

means that you're calling:

```
Enumerable.Contains(x.Col_id, ids)
```

whereas you want

```
Enumerable.Contains(ids, x.Col_id)
```

So just try:

```
var containsMethod = Expression.Call(method, value, property);
```

EDIT: Next, you're building the wrong `Contains` type argument, I think. I suspect you want:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(Enumerable).
                    GetMethods().
                    Where(x => x.Name == "Contains").
                    Single(x => x.GetParameters().Length == 2).
                    MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));
```

After all, you want to call `Enumerable.Contains<int>`, not `Enumerable.Contains<SomeType>`.

Comment: I've tried that too getting this: `Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[System.Int32]' cannot be used for type parameter 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[T] from 'Boolean Contains[T](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[T], T)' method.`

Comment: @Shin: Ah, yes - your `MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TEntidad)` is incorrect too Editing.